# Can JPA entity inherit @Version from an interface method?

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, annotations

I defined a `Versioned` interface, expecting that I could implement it on any persisted entity that I wanted to use the JPA versioning features (e.g., comparing version for mid-air collisions, auto-incrementing on updates).

```
public interface Versioned {
    @Version
    int getRevision();
}
```

This doesn't save much (if any) coding, but it also gives me a marker interface that I had plans for later.

```
public class Foo implements Versioned {
    private int revision;

    @Override
    public int getRevision() {
            return revision;
    }
}
```

`@Version` is allowed on methods, and I expected Foo to inherit that characteristic from the `Versioned` interface. That does not appear to be the case. I can update my instance of `Foo` in the database, but the revision number doesn't change automatically.

If, however, I add a `@Version` annotation to the implementation, it works as expected:

```
    @Version
    private int revision;
```

I'm not stuck - I can get the functionality I need. I'm just curious: is there a "trick" to getting this to work properly with the annotation on the interface's method? Or can someone point me to documentation of why this doesn't work as I expect?

Answer (score 3):

Annotation inheritance doesn't work on methods. From the [documentation of `@Inherited`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html):

> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated
>   type is used to annotate anything other than a class. 
>   Note also that this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from superclasses; **annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect**.

Comment: Yes, that looks like the answer. Very interesting. I am mildly surprised I never ran into this before.

Comment: I don't think \@Inherited has anything to do with this. JPA could choose to look for annotations in superclasses and interfaces. And it does, if the superclass is annotated with \@MappedSuperclass. It doesn't on interfaces, though. It's just a choice that the spec has made.

Comment: @JBNizet, I think Isaac expected annotation inheritance to work on methods, that's why I gave this answer. I agree, JPA could look in interfaces.

Comment: @WilQu Yes, that's what I expected. As I said in my first comment, I just somehow never ran into that quirk before. JB Nizet, it sounds like you're saying this is something that a JPA implementation could do, but it isn't in the spec.

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that the spec says that mapping annotations are looked for in the class itself and in the superclass if annotated with MappedSuperclass. And not in implemented interfaces.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for correcting me. Do you have a reference to the relevant portion of the specification handy? That would make your answer clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: You still can save some code by declaring version on parent entities. Say you have Class B and Class C which both extend Class A, you can define version, getVersion and setVersion in Class A and the children classes will inherit the versioning feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible.

First of all, because @MappedSuperclass is needed to inherit mapping annotations from a superclass. So I don't see why mapping annotations would automatically be inherited from an interface.

Second because if the JPA anotations in the class are on fields and not on getters, the annotations on getters will be ignored.

Paragraph 2.11.2 of the spec says:

> An entity may inherit from a superclass that provides persistent entity state and mapping information,
>   but which is not itself an entity. Typically, the purpose of such a mapped superclass is to define state
>   and mapping information that is common to multiple entity classes.
>
> A mapped superclass, unlike an entity, is not queryable and must not be passed as an argument to
>   EntityManager
>   or
>   Query
>   operations. Persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must
>   be unidirectional.
>
> Both **abstract and concrete classes may be specified as mapped superclasses**. The
>   MappedSuper-
>   class
>   annotation (or
>   mapped-superclass
>   XML descriptor element) is used to designate a
>   mapped superclass.

(emphasis mine)

This is in the chapter about inheritance, and nowhere does the spec talsk about inherited mapping from interfaces. Mapping can only be inherited from abstract or concrete classes.